# Cant Upload File in Nestjs from Client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs, prisma

Im trying to create an endpoint where user can upload a photo, and images should be saved in server,im using Nestjs/Multer,

this is the code inside user.controller

```
  @Post('/upload-photo/:id')
  @Serialize()
  @Roles(UserRole.ADMIN)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './public',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const filename: string =
            // path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(/\s/g, '') +
            // new Date().getTime();
            //uuidv4();
            file.originalname;
          const extension: string = path.parse(file.originalname).ext;
          console.log('file from multer: ', file);

          cb(null, `${filename}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  async uploadPhoto(@UploadedFile() file, @Param('id') id: string) {
    //return this.usersService.uploadPhoto();
    console.log('file from inside controller: ', file);

    //return { data: { imagePath: file.filename }, status: 200 };
    return this.usersService.uploadPhoto(file, id);
  }
```

and this is the code inside the user.service

```
  async uploadPhoto(
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    id: string,
  ): Promise<ICustomResponse> {
    try {
      const { path, destination, filename, originalname } = file;

      const modifiedPathSlashes =
        // this.config.get('app.frontendDomain') + path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
        originalname;

      const user = await this.prisma.user.update({
        where: { id: id },
        data: { photo: modifiedPathSlashes },
      });
      console.log(user);
      return getCustomResponse({
        status: HttpStatus.OK,
        success: true,
        data: user,
      });
    } catch (error) {}
    throw new BadRequestException(
*your text*      getCustomResponse({
        status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        success: false,
        errors: 'Could not update user avatar',
      }),
    );
  }
```

and it works perfectly fine when I test with postman
[Postman scr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxyPs.png)

but when the client(Reactjs) tries to upload an image it gives **400 Bad Request** and the logs I get from backend is this one *console.log('file from inside controller: ', file);* which shows that file is undefined
[Backend logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iPwI.png)

Does anyone know why im getting *undefined*? What Am I doing wrong, any suggestion what changes should I make to make it work?

Comment: Might be helpful to show what your client side request looks like if a request from postman is succeeding

Comment: How are you sending the file through your react app?

Comment: Thanks, indeed the problem was from the client, to be more exact it was the Content-Type inside the header, and it was set as "application/json" and it sent the file as a string, so had to change the Content-Type to "multipart/form-data" and the file was sent as a binary, so if anyone ever has a similar problem please make the necessary changes.